# Calculate required torque for cam design

Tags: mechanical-engineering

Would like to check the following design (snail cam) require how much motor rated torque?

To ease calculation, i have include some assumed factor as below. Two extreme condition (rotation degree) to compare.

What is the **motor rated torque** required for the design? (is 0.30Nm enough?**)

*please let know if any factor missing or not logic.

*would like to have estimation only, thus to simplify, insignificant and complicated factor can be ignore

[image: snail cam design]

Comment: This looks like homework, show what you have completed so far.

Comment: Somehow I feel friction should play a role in this problem, and calculation of the minimum torque.